# How to compare these numbers

Tags: real-analysis

How to compare **$ 3^{\pi}$** and **$\pi^{3}$**

I think this can be done by taking the function $f(x)=x^{\frac{1}{x}}$ where $x>0$, on taking first derivative i got $f^1(x)=\frac{x^{\frac{1}{x}}}{x^2}({1+log(x)})$
when $f^1(x)$ equated with zero i got $x=\frac{1}{e}$.
what i do want to know is whether the function $f(x)$ is increasing or decreasing over the interval $ x \in (e^{-1},\infty)$ 
when i tried twice first i got decreasing then i got increasing.which one is right?

Comment: sorry i didn't get you?

Comment: Oh, sorry, nevermind. My fault.

Comment: Why don't you plug in an easy value for $x$ in the interval (say, $x = 1$) and see whether $f'(x)$ is greater than or less than $0$?

Comment: ok  thats fine !

Comment: How about $e^{\pi ln3}$ and $e^{3 ln \pi}$ and seeing whether the x part  or the lnx part grows faster ( x grows faster for x>1)?

Comment: i also think like that. but no idea of how to move further.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You choose the proper function for this study but I think that you made a small mistake sincd the derivative of  $f(x)=x^{\frac{1}{x}}$ is $$f'(x)=x^{\frac{1}{x}} \left(\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{\log (x)}{x^2}\right)$$ (to obtain this result, logarithmic differentiation makes life much easier).

So, the derivative cancels at $x=e$ and this point corresponds to a maximum (second derivative test) since $$f''(x)=x^{\frac{1}{x}} \left(\frac{2 \log (x)}{x^3}-\frac{3}{x^3}\right)+x^{\frac{1}{x}}
   \left(\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{\log (x)}{x^2}\right)^2$$ which makes $$f''(e)=-e^{\frac{1}{e}-3}$$ So, the function increases up to $x=e$, goes though the maximum and then decreases.

So, since $e<3<\pi$, then $\cdots$

Comment: Oh thank you. So the answer is $3^{\pi}>\pi^{3}$

Comment: You are very welcome ! Yes  $3^{\pi}>\pi^{3}$ and $3^{\pi}-\pi^{3}\approx 0.538$